# Meteor call multiple methods with one call-command

Tags: node.js, meteor, methods

is there a nice way to call multiple methods with one Meteor.call command? I am pretty new in Meteor and Node.js. Explanations or suggestions are always welcome!

instead of:

```
Meteor.call("method1", function(err, result){
            //do something
})
Meteor.call("method2", function(err,result){
            //do something
})
```

something like this:

```
Meteor.call{("method1", function(err,result){
            //do something
       }),
       ("method2", function(err,result){
            //do something
       }),
}
```

I don't know the right syntax, but I could imagine something like this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call only one method at a time using meteor.call.
But what you can do here is create an object of your methods name then using any iterator you can call several methods. Like :

```
var myMethods = [{ name : 'method1'}, { name : 'method2'}, { name : 'method3'}, ...];
myMethods.map(function(data){
   Meteor.call(data.name, function(err,result){
            //do something
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call one method from client and on the server side (in called method) call the other server method.